# Set Title with Modal View doesn´t work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I initiate the following Modal Controller:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *modal = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modalController"];
modal.title = @"Example Title";
[self presentModalViewController:modal animated:YES];
```

I set the title with:

```
modal.title = @"Example Title";
```

but this doesn´t work, can anyone help me?

Edit:
I have wrapped my ModalView with a UINavigationController like this

[image]

Comment: Wrap `modal` within a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I have wrapped it in IB, so I get a Navigation Bar within my Modal View, but I can´t set the title through my other ViewController...

Comment: Did you create a navigation controller to wrap it or only a navigation bar? They are different things. The former is a controller. The latter a view.

Comment: I have created a Navigation Controller, here is a picture:  [link](http://g28i.img-up.net/exampleb931.png)

Comment: Are you able to upload the image editing your question? Thanks

Comment: One more question. Does your modal controller have a navigation bar? If yes, simply remove it. You can take advantage of the bar of the navigation controller. Hope that helps.

Comment: No my modal controller don´t have a Navigation Bar itself, it gets the navigationBar from the UINavigationController. Thats very curious, I can´t see a mistake, but it doesn´t work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going about this in a slightly convoluted way... but to stay with your paradigm, you need to present the *navigationController*, not the contained *viewController*: trying to do it the latter way will instantiate the viewController, but this action will not pull the containing navController along with it out of the storyboard. You are setting the viewController's title property ok, but you have no (automated) way to display the title. Whereas if you instantiate the navController, it's contained viewController does get unarchived along with it as it's `topViewController`.

```
        //give the navigation controller a storyboard id eg "navVC"
    UINavigationController* modalNav = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navVC"];
    [modalNav topViewController].title = @"Example Title";

        //[self presentModalViewController:modalNav animated:YES];
        //deprecated method, use this instead:
    [self presentViewController:modalNavController 
                       animated:YES
                    completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a IBOutlet property for UINavigationItem (the title) in your model controller with a classic drag & drop method.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navTitle;
```

Then set the title in viewDidLoad function.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // title view
    [self.navTitle setTitle: @"atitle"];
}
```